# Loop through xml NSData variable and get values in swift 2.1

Tags: ios, foreach, xml-parsing, swift2, swxmlhash

I'm new to swift programming.

I wrote a code which gets `xml` output from `rss` feed and parse it into `NSDATA` type,
then I want to get `title` and `image` `src`  values from it in a loop and send them to a table view to create a list.

when I get those values manually I mean like :

```
let appName = xml["rss"]["channel"]["item"][0]["title"].element!.text!
let appUrl = xml["rss"]["channel"]["item"][0]["description"]["img"].element!.attributes["src"]
```

my code works ok and one item creates in table view correctly. 
but the problem is when I want to get all values from xml file.

I couldn't create and array of the xml which is NSDATA type, not a string to be able to loop through it.

all I could manage to work is the below code which returns all xml tags value which I don't want that :

```
func enumerate(indexer: XMLIndexer, level: Int) {
                for child in indexer.children {
                    let appName = child.element!.text
                    let appUrl = child.element!.attributes["src"]


                    let ap = Apps(name: appName , img : appUrl)
                    self.tableData.append(ap)

                    self.tableView.reloadData()

                    enumerate(child, level: level + 1)
                }
            }

            enumerate(xml, level: 0)
```

Any Idea how to get those values in a loop without mistaking or getting other values?

here is my code :

```
     let url = NSURL(string: "http://razavitv.aqr.ir/index/rss/2")

        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!) {(data, response, error) in


            let dataString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as! String

            let processedString = (dataString as NSString).stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("<![CDATA[", withString: "").stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("]]", withString: "") as String

            let data: NSData = processedString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

            let xml = SWXMLHash.parse(data)


//                    let appName = xml["rss"]["channel"]["item"][0]["title"].element!.text!
//                    let appUrl = xml["rss"]["channel"]["item"][0]["description"]["img"].element!.attributes["src"]
//    
//                    let ap = Apps(name: appName , img : appUrl)
//                    self.tableData.append(ap)
//            
//                    self.tableView.reloadData()




            func enumerate(indexer: XMLIndexer, level: Int) {
                for child in indexer.children {
                    let appName = child.element!.text
                    let appUrl = child.element!.attributes["src"]


                    let ap = Apps(name: appName , img : appUrl)
                    self.tableData.append(ap)

                    self.tableView.reloadData()

                    enumerate(child, level: level + 1)
                }
            }

            enumerate(xml, level: 0)


        }

        task.resume()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

very simple solution :  just need to create a for loop with indexer inside.

here is the code :

```
   //one root element
        let count = xml["rss"]["channel"]["item"].all.count



        for var i = 0; i < count; i++ {
                let appName = xml["rss"]["channel"]["item"][i]["title"].element!.text!
                let appUrl = xml["rss"]["channel"]["item"][i]["description"]["img"].element!.attributes["src"]



                let ap = Apps(name: appName , img : appUrl)
                self.tableData.append(ap)

                self.tableView.reloadData()

        }
```